# What's wrong with this search query (Python and SQLite3)?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to search my database and show the results, but my code is returning nothing, and I can't figure out where the mistake is.

This is how I'm scraping the data and inserting it into the database:

```
def getJobsData(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    data = []
    for e in soup.select('.card'):
        data.append({
            'title': e.h2.text,
            'desc': e.ul.get_text('\n', strip=True)
            })
    
    try:
        for item in data:
            c.execute('''INSERT INTO job VALUES(?,?)''',
                (item['title'], item['desc']))
        return
    except:
        return
```

And this is the search code:

```
@app.route("/search", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    error = ""
    user_input = None
    data = None
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            conn = sqlite3.connect('jobs.db')
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute('''SELECT * FROM job WHERE title = (?,)''', (request.form["search"],))
            data = c.fetchall()
            user_input = (request.form["search"],)
            return render_template("search.html", data=data, user_input=user_input)

    except Exception as e:
        error = (str(e))
        return render_template("search.html", error=error, user_input=user_input)
```

HTML:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="POST" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search" value="{{ request.form.search }}">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

I'm using Python, Flask and SQLite3.
What did I do wrong and how do I fix this? Thank you!

**EDIT:** I've realized that the code does return the data from the database, but the search query has to match exactly to the title. Trying to figure out how to solve this. Here's what I updated, print statements are there just for testing:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        conn = sqlite3.connect('jobs.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        user_input = request.form["search"]
        data = c.execute('''SELECT * FROM job WHERE title LIKE ?''', (user_input,)).fetchall()
        print("USER INPUT:" + user_input)
        print(data)
        for d in data:
            print(d)
        return render_template("search.html", data=data, user_input=user_input)
```

Comment: `except: return` is less than useless for understanding what's going on. If there's an error there, it is completely hidden from you. Remove that

Comment: How did you try to debug it? Did you confirm the table actually contains that data? did you confirm how the post request looks like on the server?

Comment: Yes, the database does contain data, I'm displaying it on another template without any issues. And I've tried to adjust the SELECT statement so many times. How do I confirm how the post request looks on the server?

Comment: `print(request.json)` or `print(request.form.to_dict())`?

Comment: Thank you, roganjosh, for the assistance! I've realized that the code does return the data from the database 100%, but the search query I type in has to match exactly to the title. Trying to figure out how to solve this.

Comment: Yup, currently researching LIKE and how to use it with a variable and data from that variable in any position! Thank you, DeepSpace.

Answer (score 0):

The `=` operator in SQL should take a single value:

```py
c.execute('''SELECT * FROM job WHERE title = ?''', (request.form["search"],))
# Here --------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mureinik. But I'm still getting just an empty list as a result. Trying to figure out if perhaps I'm not writing the SELECT statement correctly at all, to get the data.